# Compare two associative arrays by key

Tags: php, array

I am currently for a program I am writing needing to compare two associative arrays by key and value in PHP and get the common elements as well as the difference between the common elements.

I have currently arrived at the following solution:

```
<?php
$newArr = [0 => ['id' => 'UT5', 'qty' => '4'], 1 => ['id' => 'WRO', 'qty' => '3'], 2 => ['id' => 'SHO', 'qty' => '3']];

$oldArr = [0 => ['id' => 'SHO', 'qty' => '1'], 1 => ['id' => 'UT5', 'qty' => '2'], ];

$newReset = [];
foreach( $newArr as $item ) {
    $newReset[$item['id']] = $item['qty'];
}

$oldReset = [];
foreach( $oldArr as $item ) {
    $oldReset[$item['id']] = $item['qty'];
}

foreach( $newReset as $key => $val ) {
    if( isset( $oldReset[$key] ) ) {
        $toAdd[$key] = max( $oldReset[$key], $val ) - min( $oldReset[$key], $val );
    }
    else $toAdd[$key] = intval($val);
}

var_dump( $toAdd );
```

I am just curious as to how I can go about implementing perhaps array functions or an array function with a closure etc... to refactor the approach or use another method entirely?

For reference, my output is currently as follows:

array(3) {  ["UT5"]=> int(2)  ["WRO"]=> int(3)  ["SHO"]=> int(2) }

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like you are getting common elements + unique original elements. Do you want *only* common elements?

Comment: Could you clarify if you're asking for a review or asking for help writing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce your code in several ways.

First, since you seem to want the *absolute* value of the difference between `qty`s for the same ìd`:

```
$toAdd[$key] = max( $oldReset[$key], $val ) - min( $oldReset[$key], $val );
```

It can be achieved more simply:

```
$toAdd[$key] = abs($oldReset[$key] - $val);
```

BTW, when `id` doesn't exist in `$oldReset` you probably want the same, so you should use `$toAdd[$key] = abs($val);` instead of `$toAdd[$key] = intval($val);` (but maybe you are sure that `qty` is always positive).

On the other hand, you're preparing both `$newArr` and `$oldArr` to get a simplified version of the form `array(id => qty)`: you can do it for only one array, so using less code and probably working faster.

With all the changes proposed above, your whole code becomes:

```
$oldReset = [];
foreach ($oldArr as $item) {
  $oldReset[$item['id']] = $item['qty'];
}
foreach ($newArr as $key => $val) {
  $id = $val['id'];
  $qty = $val['qty'];
  if (isset($oldReset[$id])) {
    $toAdd[$id] = abs($oldReset[$id] - $qty);
  }
  else {
    $toAdd[$id] = abs($qty);
  }
}
```

Last point, I notice that you don't try to detect `id`s existing in `$oldArray` and not present in `$newArray`. But again maybe you're sure it cannot happen.

Answer (score 0):

Use `abs( a - b )` instead of `max(a,b) - min(a,b)`.. its easier read and to see you are taking the difference

If only want to iterate over a set of common elements, `array_intersect_keys` will give you that set.

```
$newArr = array(
  0 => array('id' => 'UT5', 'qty' => '4'),
  1 => array('id' => 'WRO', 'qty' => '3'),
  2 => array('id' => 'SHO', 'qty' => '3'),
);
$oldArr = array(
  0 => array('id' => 'SHO', 'qty' => '1'),
  1 => array('id' => 'UT5', 'qty' => '2'),
);

foreach ($newArr as $item) $newReset[$item['id']] = $item['qty'];
foreach ($oldArr as $item) $oldReset[$item['id']] = $item['qty'];

foreach (array_keys(array_intersect_key($newReset, $oldReset)) as $key) {
  $toAdd[$key] = abs($oldReset[$key] - $newReset[$key]);
}

print_r($toAdd);
```

if you wanted to include keys not set in `$oldArr` but set in `$newArr`

```
print_r(array_merge($newReset, $toAdd));
```

Comment: You should include more text explaining the reason you used this approach?